# How can I add a delay between function calls that change data in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a function, `my_fn`, that changes the data of some elements and transitions them.

I want to call that function in a for loop, such that the changes and transitions happen one at a time, with a brief pause in between them.

Here's a snippet that may not run on its own but shows the problem:

```
function updateData(){
  for (i=0; i<20; i++){
    my_fn();
    //console.log('sleeping...');
    //sleep(300);
  }
}

function my_fn(){

  var delay_amount = 300;

  focus.selectAll('circle')
    .transition()
    .delay(delay_amount)
    .attr('cy', function(d, i){
      if (d.index == 5){
        d.y += change_amount;
      }
      return y(d.y);
    });
}
```

I'm trying to use d3's `delay()` function for the transition. However, when I run this, it pauses (for the delay amount), and then all the circles move at once. From this, it seems like `my_fn` is getting called immediately 20 times, all the transitions are delayed, and then they all happen at once.

To get around this, I tried adding the commented code in `updateData()` (with a sleep function that just waits in a while loop). That seems to wait 20 of those 300 ms sleep cycles, and THEN does the transitions all at once.

**What's going on? How can I achieve this?**

NB: I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534333/how-do-i-add-a-transition-delay-between-multiple-individual-transitioning-polygo), and it appears to be asking a similar thing, but the answer doesn't seem to work. I believe it's because their "loop" is called from a `selectAll`, though I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that `my_fn()` is getting called immediately. The `delay()` call has no effect on the for loop, so all 20 calls to `my_fn()` are being scheduled immediately.

To get the effect you are looking for, you'd have to use a callback so that the next call to `my_fn()` isn't made until the previous one finishes. You can do this with d3 like so

```js
function my_fn(){

  var delay_amount = 300;

  focus.selectAll('circle')
    .transition()
    .delay(delay_amount)
    .attr('cy', function(d, i){
      if (d.index == 5){
        d.y += change_amount;
      }
      return y(d.y);
    })
    .on('end', my_fn);
}
```

Or if you really wanted to use a for loop, you could use setTimeout like so:

```js
function updateData(){
  for (i=0; i<20; i++){
    setTimeout(my_fn, 300 * i);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Note that the first example will recursively call `my_fn()` forever, so you would need to implement some kind of logic to stop after the twentieth call.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!! It works perfectly. Yeah I'd rather use the explicit for loop and timeout, because I want to be able to externally trigger them/etc. I also found `d3.queue` (https://github.com/d3/d3-queue) while doing this, is that another way? I briefly tried it but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Yeah! The `d3.queue` module would probably work perfectly for what you are doing. When creating the queue, specify the concurrency as 1 so that all tasks are ran in series, otherwise they will all run in parallel. You will also have to add the callback parameter to `my_fn()` like the examples so that the queue knows when to execute the next task

Comment: Just as a curiosity, here is another way to use `setTimeout` in loops: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37563825/5768908.